# How to dynamically save information is functions?

Tags: python, function, variables, save

So, I'm trying to make this choose-your-own adventure game where you need to manipulate two locks to beat it. But I'm having issues trying to make the Silver and Gold lock position functions change during the program run. I've tried changing the positions of the functions and the value of the functions, but the code keeps breaking, is there something I'm missing?

```
Left = 'Left'
Right = 'Right'
Center = 'Center'

SilverLockPosition = Left
GoldLockPosition = Right

game = True

def win():
  print('You won!')

while game == True:
  print("\nThe door that you came in dissapears behind you. In front of you, there is a door in front of you, and both sides of you. Where do you go?")
  HallwayChoice = input("\n(o)pen front door\n(l)eft entryway exit\n(r)ight entryway exit\nWhere to?:") #-- Choice of which room to enter.
  if HallwayChoice == 'o':
    CurrentRoom = 'o'
    if SilverLockPosition == Left and GoldLockPosition == Right:
      print("You twist open the knob and the door unlocks!")
      win()
    else:
      print("You pull on the door with all your might but it won't open! Is there a room you haven't checked?")
  elif HallwayChoice == 'l':
    CurrentRoom = 'l'
    print("\nYou're in a pantry stocked with the usual foodstuffs. In front of you is a lock with 3 positions, it is currently in in the left position. Behind you is the door to the entrance. What do you do?")
    SilverLockPosition = input("The silver lock is currently set to the %s position.\n(l)eft position turn for the silver lock\n(r)ight position turn for the silver lock\n(c)enter position turn for the silver lock\n(d)on't change the position! Return to entranceway.\nWhat do you do?" %(Left))
    if SilverLockPosition == 'l':
      SilverLockPosition = Left
      print('You set the Lock to the left.')
    elif SilverLockPosition == 'r':
      SilverLockPosition = Right
      print('You set the Lock to the right.')
    elif SilverLockPosition == 'c':
      SilverLockPosition = Center
      print('You set the Lock to the center.')
    elif SilverLockPosition == 'd':
      print('You left the room.')
  elif HallwayChoice == 'r':
    CurrentRoom = 'l'
    print("\nYou're in a kitchen with many modern appliances. In front of you is gold lock with 3 positions: left, center and right. Behind you is the doorway to the entranceway. What do you do?")
    GoldLockPosition = input("The Gold lock is currently set to the %s position.\n(l)eft position turn for the silver lock\n(r)ight position turn for the silver lock\n(c)enter position turn for the silver lock\n(d)on't change the position! Return to entranceway.\nWhat do you do?" % (Center))
    if GoldLockPosition == 'l':
      GoldLockPosition = Left
      print('You set the Lock to the left.')
    elif SilverLockPosition == 'r':
      GoldLockPosition = Right
      print('You set the Lock to the right.')
    elif GoldLockPosition == 'c':
      GoldLockPosition = Center
      print('You set the Lock to the center.')
    elif GoldLockPosition == 'd':
      print('You left the room.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I spotted a few issues with your code:

- You're using the same variable for the keys' positions and for the player's choices regarding keys. For example in line 26, **SilverLockPosition = input("The silver lock...** could become **SilverLockChoice = input("The silver lock...**
  (of course you'll have to change the variable used in the following tests too)
- Again in line 26, %s references %(Left), so the text will always mention that the key is in the left position; you should instead reference %SilverLockPosition so the text mentions the actual position of the key; you should do the same for the print command in line 25.

By the way, an alternative to using %s could be print("...in the " + SilverLockPosition + " position...")

Of course you'll have to do the same fixes for the gold key.

I hope this will help you fix your issues. Have fun working on your game.